# Error using Rmarkdown "eval"

Tags: r-markdown

While converting a normal R file to .Rmd file, iam getting this error :
iam currently using "dplyr"package

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "%>%"
>   Calls:  ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval

Comment: have you loaded the library explicit in the RMD file? `library(dplyr)`

Comment: yes ,already added dplyr library